# How do i install WHL files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-wheel

I have been having trouble installing PyWin32. I am using Python 3.6.4. When I try to install PyWin32 with the following command:

```
C:\Users\EUUUghhHH\Downloads>  pip install pywin32-223-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

it will just return

```
 pywin32-223-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I am using Windows 10 64 bit with Python 3.6.4. Thanks if you can help!

Comment: I think its not suitable wheel for this platform. Have you try to install another version? Maybe 32bits?

Comment: I have the same issue, when I try to install `pywin32-224-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` on linux. python version: 3.5.2.